# Passing a SqlCommand as an argument to a function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class called `DbVms` like this:

```
public class DbVms
{       
    private bool insertApprovals(List<Approval> approvals, string user, SqlCommand command, out string resultDesc)
    {
        resultDesc = "";
        bool result = false;

        command.Parameters.Clear();
        command.Parameters.Add("@estNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        command.Parameters.Add("@custID", SqlDbType.Int);
        command.Parameters.Add("@brandName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        command.Parameters.Add("@createdBy", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

        try
        {
            // Now add the approvals back based on whats passed in.
            foreach (Approval approval in approvals) // loop through approvals and do insert.
            {
                command.CommandText =
                "INSERT INTO [Approvals] (vendorEstNo, customerID, brand, createdBy) VALUES (@estNo, @custID, @brandName, @createdBy)";

                command.Parameters["@estNo"].Value = approval.vendorEstNo;
                command.Parameters["@custID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(approval.customerID);
                command.Parameters["@brandName"].Value = approval.brandName;
                command.Parameters["@createdBy"].Value = user;

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            result = true;
            resultDesc = "All records are written to database.";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            resultDesc = "insertApprovals - Threw an exception of type: " + ex.GetType();
        }

        return result;
    }

    private bool insertQualifications(List<Qualification> qualifications, string user,SqlCommand command, out string resultDesc)
    {
        resultDesc = "";
        bool result = false;

        command.Parameters.Clear();
        command.Parameters.Add("@estNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        command.Parameters.Add("@qualityID", SqlDbType.Int);
        command.Parameters.Add("@brandName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        command.Parameters.Add("@createdBy", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

        try
        {           
            // Now add the qualifications back based on whats passed in.
            foreach (Qualification qualification in qualifications) // loop through qualifications and do insert.
            {
                command.CommandText =
                "INSERT INTO [Qualifications] (vendorEstNo, qualityID, brand, createdBy) VALUES (@estNo, @qualityID, @brandName, @createdBy)";

                command.Parameters["@estNo"].Value = qualification.vendorEstNo;
                command.Parameters["@qualityID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(qualification.qualityID);
                command.Parameters["@brandName"].Value = qualification.brandName;
                command.Parameters["@createdBy"].Value = user;

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            result = true;
            resultDesc = "All records are written to database.";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            resultDesc = "insertQualifications - Threw an exception of type: " + ex.GetType();
        }      

        return result;
    }

    public bool updateVendorData(string estNo, List<Approval> approvals, List<Qualification> qualifications, string user, out string resultDesc)
    {
        bool result = false;
        resultDesc = "";

        string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConn"].ConnectionString;
        using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("transcation1");
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.Transaction = transaction;

            result = insertApprovals(approvals, user, cmd, out resultDesc); 

            if(result) // if approvals got inserted successfully insert qualifications
                result = insertQualifications(qualifications, user, cmd, out resultDesc);

            if (result) // if both approvals and qualifications got inserted successfully - commit transcation
            {
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            else // rollback otherwise.
            {
                try
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    resultDesc += " -- Successfully rolled back!";
                }
                catch (Exception ex2)
                {
                    // This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred
                    // on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as
                    // a closed connection.
                    resultDesc = "Rollback Exception Type: {0}" + ex2.GetType();
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Is there any problems with passing a `SqlCommand` as a function argument? Do I need to make it a ref/an out variable?

My goal here is to do the two insert statements in two separate functions and if any of them fails I want to be able to roll back the whole transaction.

Which is why I am passing the same `SqlCommand` variable to both functions and rolling back the transaction if any of them fails. But I'm a bit confused if I should pass the `SqlCommand` by reference or not.

Comment: Should i be passing it by reference?..

Comment: What, in your mind, is the benefit of passing it by reference? If you can't think of one, the answer is No - you shouldn't pass it by reference.

Comment: Trying to reuse a command here for different purposes each time *will not help you*; this is simply not a good thing to be doing in the first place. What are you trying to achieve here? I could get behind a `DbConnection` parameter, but a command? really doesn't make sense here, IMO.

Comment: I am trying to do both inserts (insertQualifications and insertApprovals) but if one of them fails  i want to be able to roll back the entire transaction.  That's why I went with this approach.

Comment: @psj01 that's like saying "I want my car to be able to get up steep hills, that's why I bought a green one"; the two things are unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My goal here is to do the two insert statements in two separate functions and if any of them fails I want to be able to roll back the whole transaction. Which is why I am passing the same SqlCommand variable to both functions and rolling back the Transaction if any of them fails.

Using the same command is not a requirement for this. All you need is the same `DbConnection`, and assign the same `DbTransaction` to each command. The actual commands should probably be local to the methods - there's no need for them to escape that context.

Comment: I updated my code to this [here](https://pastebin.com/LEPAdwgL). Is this a better approach? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @psj01 no, now you're creating the transaction inside each, and you *incorrectly* disposed the connection inside the method (which means you'll break the connection); if you want one transaction, you need to open the connection and transaction *outside*, and *pass them in*, leaving them alone (not disposing them). Also, `DbCommand` is `IDisposable`, so you should be `using` the command

Comment: so I'd have to pass an SqlConnection and an sqlTranscation to both insertApprovals and insertQualifications methods?

Comment: @psj01 the transaction already carries `.Connection` as a property, so you *could* just pass in the  transaction

Comment: Ah ok yup i see it now.  Thanks so much. if you don't mind.. what would happen if I do a  connection.BeginTranscation("samename") inside each methods (insertApproval and insertQualifications).. that would mean I'd have to commit/rollback those transcations with in those method itself or a commit/rollback in the calling method (updateVendorData) would be enough?...

Comment: Updated my code to this [here](https://pastebin.com/uKNHfWza). Seems to be working as expected.  I also changed the sqlCommand inside a using command.  Thanks so much for your help and advice.